# Identifying a device by retrieving its USB ID

Tags: vb.net, usb, usbserial

I'd like my application to be able to detect a where a particular USB device has been mounted, and adapt accordingly. Ideally, I'd associate paths with a USB serial number, rather than with a given path. However, I cannot figure out a simple way to access these unique IDs from VB.Net code.

Has anybody succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use WMI to query for the Win32_USBControllerDevice class. [Here is a blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/02/24/displaying-usb-devices-using-wmi.aspx) showing some sample code with Powershell which you should be able to adapt easily.